# Why did it failed to load? the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have my app(express+Next.js.MOngoDB).I signuped all my users,works Ok. Now when I try signin

```
http://localhost:5000/signin
```

I got error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16)
    at settle (webpack-internal:///../../node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17)
```

Terminal

```
GET /__nextjs_original-stack-frame?isServerSide=false&file=webpack-internal%3A%2F%2F%2F..%2F..%2
```

POSTMAN signin works fine
[image]

app.js(just API)

```
const app = express();
app.use('/api/v1/auth', auth);
```

Next.js,Signin

```
import SigninComponent from '../components/frontauth/SigninComponent';

const Signin = () => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <h2 className="text-center pt-3 pb-4">Signin</h2>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                    <SigninComponent />
                </div>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    );
};
```

SigninComponent
/* eslint-disable no-undef */

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { API } from '../../config';

const SigninComponent = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    });
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const { email, password } = values;

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { email, password } = values;
        const user = { email, password};
        await axios.post(`${API}/api/v1/auth/signin`, user);

    };

    const handleChange = name => e => {
        setValues({ ...values, error: false, [name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const showLoading = () => (loading ? <div className="alert alert-info">Loading...</div> : '');

    const signinForm = () => {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                        value={values.email}
                        onChange={handleChange('email')}
                        type="email"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Type your email"
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                        value={values.password}
                        onChange={handleChange('password')}
                        type="password"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Type your password"
                    />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Signin</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    };

    return <React.Fragment>
    {showLoading()}
    {signinForm()} 
     </React.Fragment>;
};

export default SigninComponent;
```

How should I edit .babelrc,I have only one line,should I add plugins?

```
  "presets": ["next/babel"]
```

Why does the terminal point to SSR FALSE?

Comment: Could you post the relevant code that triggers the error?

Comment: @juliomalves I just added signin component.

Comment: Does the sign-in request work using Postman?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes,it works,I will add this.

Comment: In Postman you're making a request against `/api/v1/auth/login` while in your code you have `/api/v1/auth/signin`. That's probably why?